# Passing 'NSTimeInterval' (aka double) to parameter of incompatible type'CGFloat' aka 'float'

Tags: ios7, xcode5, sprite-kit

```
-(void)movePipes
{
    [_gameLayer enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"pole" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
        SKSpriteNode *poleSprite = (SKSpriteNode *) node;
        if (poleSprite.position.x < -50) {
            [poleSprite removeFromParent];
        }
        else
        {
            CGPoint distanceToMove = CGPointMake(-PIPE_POINTS_PER_SEC, 0);
            CGPoint amtToMove = CGPointMultiplyScalar(distanceToMove, _dt);
            poleSprite.position = CGPointAdd(amtToMove, poleSprite.position);
        }
    }];

}
```

This throws the following error:

```
Passing 'NSTimeInterval' (aka double) to parameter of incompatible type'CGFloat' aka 'float'
```

Comment: So which variable has type `NSTimeInterval`?

Comment: Please add more description. In your code snippet, where is the `NSTimeInterval` type variable?